# Arduino Error in connecting with ESP32 CAM - Compilation error: exec: "cmd": executable file not found in %PATH%

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide

```
Using board 'esp32wrover' from platform in folder: C:\Users\Thurunu\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6
```

Using core 'esp32' from platform in folder: C:\Users\Thurunu\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.6
cmd /c if exist "C:\Users\Thurunu\Downloads\arduino-esp32-master\arduino-esp32-master\libraries\ESP32\examples\Camera\CameraWebServer\partitions.csv" copy /y "C:\Users\Thurunu\Downloads\arduino-esp32-master\arduino-esp32-master\libraries\ESP32\examples\Camera\CameraWebServer\partitions.csv" "C:\Users\Thurunu\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\B3492542C1D8028DB5AD7AD93B5DBA1C\partitions.csv"

exec: "cmd": executable file not found in %PATH%

Compilation error: exec: "cmd": executable file not found in %PATH%

I updated the path variable to the cmd.exe`s path and still  the problem didn't resolved. I un installed the Arduino IDE several times but the problem still prevails.

I am using the Arduino IDE 2.0.4

Comment: I think you have to add "C:\Windows\System32\" to the environmental variables but try to run the Arduino IDE as admin. I am running into the same issue. I will let you know if I can fix it. Please let me know if you have fixed it.

Comment: Responding to my older comment, I managed to fix it by adding "C:\Windows\System32\" to Environment variables (you can search for it on Windows 10/11) or System Properties (Advanced Tab) and the bottom that says Environment Variables... I added it to "System variables", and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When i updated my IDE and ESP 32 i getting the same error so, i added to the user variable PATH the path where the cmd.exe 64 is, usually in "C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64".